# Creating some kind of validation rule

Tags: php, html, forms, validation

I am trying to create a log in form which allows user to log in,  based on their registration details (which is saved in a flat file) and this what I have come up with so far.

At the moment the this code allow any user to log in even when there are not on the registration.

```
<html>
<body>
<table align="center">
<tr>
<th><h3>MY ACCOUNT</h3></th>
</tr>

<form action = "index.php" method = "POST">
<tr>
<td>Username:</br><input type="text" name="username"></br></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Password:</br><input type="password" name="password"></br></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td align = "center"><input type="submit" name = "submit"></td>
</tr>
</form>
</table>
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$file = file_get_contents("data.txt");

if(empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password'])){
die (print '<script> alert ("You must enter both your username and password to continue."); window.location="index.php"; </script>');
}

if(!strstr($file, "$username#$password")) {
die(print '<script> alert ("Wrong"); window.location="index.php"; </script>');
}
else {
header("Location: wacc.php");
}
}


?>
```

Please what is wrong with code

Comment: What's wrong with the one (answer) I gave you earlier? It worked 100% you changed something, one of them being the seperator `#` that you have now. I wouldn't use that.

Comment: @Fred-ii- yeah it works but it allow any users to log in, without any registration.

Comment: My original version to you did not allow that, I made sure of that, which is what I don't understand now. I would not have given you code that didn't work, I'm not like that.

Answer (score 1):

In your other post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20612879/how-to-use-php-to-create-a-resgister-and-a-login-form) you were given a suggestion to use a script called PHP Login. This would help solve a lot of your problems if you follow this suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you change the `strstr` to the `strpos` function, it's the desired function for checking if a string occurs, and works ok.

So:

`if(!strstr($file, "$username#$password")) {`

To:

`if(strpos($file, "$username#$password") === false) {`

Note the === , it needs to be false, not 0 or ''. See for more info http://www.php.net/function.strpos

**Edit**

The logging in always is most of the time true, because whats happening is that your searching for if the specified string is occurring in your text document. Now, incase that if you leave both fields $username and $password empty, it will be true ( is there a # in the text document? Yes. ) This also applies when you write a valid part username or password.

I would suggest you rethink this login system, and use a PHP array or database to match a valid username and password. If you just want a simple bump for visitors, try adding an delimiter.

In your username and password list for example:

`#username#password#`

And as strpos function

`if(strpos($file, "#$username#$password#") === false) {`

With adding the # before and after, your script always nows where the username must start and must end, and the same for the password. If the username was too short, too long, or empty the # gets added anyway and will the strpos will then be wrong (is there an ### in the list? No.).

Comment: it might work but one of the left bracket is missing but thanks though.

Comment: Actually there was an bracket too much, changed it, should work now

Answer (score 0):

you could use facebook login instead.

I dont think a flat file login could ever be totally secure.  /shrug.

Facebook is really easy though and is a multi-billion dollar corporation that pays programmers to make it as secure as possible.  No need to worry about security at all.

```
<?php
require 'fbconfig.php';   // Include fbconfig.php file
?>
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
  <head>
    <title>Login with Facebook</title>
<link href="http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
 </head>
  <body>
  <?php if ($user): ?>      <!--  After user login  -->
<div class="container">
<div class="hero-unit">
  <h1>Hello <?php echo $fbuname; ?></h1>
  <p>Welcome to "facebook login" tutorial</p>
  </div>
<div class="span4">
 <ul class="nav nav-list">
<li class="nav-header">Image</li>
    <li><img src="https://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo $user; ?>/picture"></li>
<li class="nav-header">Facebook ID</li>
<li><?php echo  $fbid; ?></li>
<li class="nav-header">Facebook Username</li>
<li><?php echo $fbuname; ?></li>
<li class="nav-header">Facebook fullname</li>
<li><?php echo $fbfullname; ?></li>
<div><a href="<?php echo $logoutUrl; ?>">Logout</a></div>
</ul></div></div>
    <?php else: ?>     <!-- Before login --> 
<div class="container">
<h1>Login with Facebook</h1>
           Not Connected
<div>
      <a href="<?php echo $loginUrl; ?>">Login with Facebook</a></div>
      </div>
    <?php endif ?>
  </body>
</html>
```